# foreach loop mixes up result

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach

I'm struggeling with following situation:

**testfile.txt**

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

**Script:**

```
$input = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\testfile.txt"

foreach ($line in $input) {
    $var1 = $line.Substring(2,1)
    $output = "$var1 is $var2"

    if ($line -match "1") {
        $var2 = "1"
        Write-Host $output
    } elseif ($line -match "2") {
        $var2 = "2"
        Write-Host $output
    } elseif ($line -match "3") {
        $var2 = "3"
        Write-Host $output
    } else {}
}
```

**Result:**

```
a is 3
b is 1
c is 2
```

Why is the result mixed up? It should be:

```
a is 1
b is 2
c is 3
```

Even if I put the `$output` at the end of the `foreach` loop?!

Comment: Move `$output = "$var1 is $var2"` before `Write-Host`, as it's not a template but an immediately expanded substitution which uses previous values.

Comment: Of course it will work then. But is it really necessary to put it in each if statement?

Comment: Or you could change each Write-Host to `Write-Host "$var1 is $var2"`

Comment: Actually your entire code can be written as `(Get-Content "C:\Scripts\testfile.txt") -replace '(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '$1 is $2'` If you want tempates, use a [script block method](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/05/22/variable-substitution-in-a-powershell-script-block/).

Comment: Yeah, this was only a simplified example of my original script. I will solve it like you showed it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

You probably ran the code before, because normally your output should look like this:

```
a is
b is 1
c is 2
```

The `3` in your first output line is obviously retained from a previous attempt.

The reason for this behavior is that you only assign a value to `$var2` *after* you assign `"$var1 is $var2"` to a variable. The variables in the string are already expanded upon assignment, so you get the value of `$var2` from the previous iteration (or an empty value on the first run).

To get the output you want change your code to this:

```
foreach ($line in $input) {
    $var1 = $line.Substring(2,1)
    $output = "$var1 is {0}"

    if ($line -match '1') {
        Write-Host ($output -f '1')
    } elseif ($line -match '2') {
        Write-Host ($output -f '2')
    } elseif ($line -match '3') {
        Write-Host ($output -f '3')
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
foreach ($line in $input) {
    $var1 = $line.Substring(2,1)

    $var2 = if ($line -match '1') {
        '1'
    } elseif ($line -match '2') {
        '2'
    } elseif ($line -match '3') {
        '3'
    }

    if ($var2) {
        Write-Host "$var1 is $var2"
    }
}
```

Better yet, since you're using a regular expression match anyway, do something like this:

```
foreach ($line in $input) {
    $var1 = $line.Substring(2,1)

    if ($line -match '[1-3]') {
        Write-Host "$var1 is $($matches[0])"
    }
}
```